# How to get parameters in the reaction native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to pass parameters to a view. I followed some examples, but to no avail. How do I do it?

A part of my code:

Home:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

import colors from '../../components/colors';
import Shoe from '../../components/home/shoe';
import Teste from '../teste';
import Detail from '../detail';

export default function Home(props) {
    return(
        <View style={styles.storeProducts_line}>
            <Shoe 
               source={require('../../images/home/tenisAdidasFalconFeminino.jpg')}
               title="Tênis Adidas Falcon Feminino"
               price="200,00"

               onClick={() => props.navigation.navigate('Detail', {
                   productId: 12,
                   productTitle: 'Tênis Adidas',
               })}
            />
            <Shoe 
               source={require('../../images/home/tenisAdidasYeezySalt.jpg')}
               title="Tênis Adidas Yeezy Salt"
               price="175,90"
               onClick={() => navigation.navigate('Detail')}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Detail:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function Detail({props, navigation}) {

   const productId = navigation.getParam('userId');
   // const productId = props.navigation.getParam('userId');

   return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image 
          />
          <Text>
              Detail
          </Text>
          <Text>
              {productId}
          </Text>
      </View>
   );
}
```

All the examples I saw the structure of the view is different, do I have to change the structure to work? I'm new to react-native, bear with me. Thanks in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `route` to access the passed data from parent component.

Example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function Detail({route, navigation}) {

   const {productId} = route.params;
   // const productId = props.navigation.getParam('userId');

   return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image 
          />
          <Text>
              Detail
          </Text>
          <Text>
              {productId}
          </Text>
      </View>
   );
}
```

For more please do read this doc: [Passing parameters to routes](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params)

Comment: Thank you very much !

Comment: In an edit, you suggested to use ```route.params.productId``` which works fine, but if you have more than one parameter to be accessed then destructing is a much cleaner way, just like we did in ```Detail({route, navigation})``` :)